# How can i select multiple rows having the sum of a column lower than a specific value?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called 'markers ' that have the structure like this:

```
 +------+---------------+-----------+-------------+
 |  id  |      about    |    time   |     type    |
 |------|---------------|-----------|-------------|
 |   1  |      text     |     2     |  restaurant |
 |------|---------------|-----------|-------------|
 |   2  |      text     |     1     |  restaurant |
 |------|---------------|-----------|-------------|
 |   3  |      text     |     2     |    museum   |
 |------|---------------|-----------|-------------|
 |   4  |      text     |     2     |     park    |
 +------+---------------+-----------+-------------+
```

From this table i want to select a combination of rows so that the sum of time is lower or equal to a specific value. For example i want to select row number 1,3 and 4 because the total time is lower or equal with 6. 
I think the query should sound like this: `SELECT 'all rows' WHERE SUM(time) < 6`, but it doesn't work that simple.
Another question, that maybe comes, is if i choose the sum to be equal with 3, in this case i have several combinations ( row 1 with row 2, row 2 with row 3..and so one ). What can i do to choose one value of each type ? 
I hope i made myself understood. Thanks in advance !

```
SELECT id, time, type 
FROM `markers` 
WHERE type IN (
     SELECT type FROM markers 
     WHERE (type = 'restaurant' OR type = 'museum' OR type = 'park') 
     GROUP BY type HAVING SUM(time_to_spend)< 20
     )
```

For 3 i would expect at something like this:

     `+------+---------------+-----------+-------------+
     |  id  |      about    |    time   |     type    |
     |------|---------------|-----------|-------------|
     |   2  |      text     |     1     |  restaurant |
     |------|---------------|-----------|-------------|
     |   3  |      text     |     2     |    museum   |
     |------|---------------|-----------|-------------|`
or any other combination.

Comment: Can you post the expected output say for 3?

Comment: Sounds like you're going to need to use some recursion. Here is a SQL solution to the knapsack problem which is similar enough to your problem that you might be able to adapt it http://aprogrammerwrites.eu/?p=560

Comment: Thanks, i will try your proposed link and i will come back with more info's. Regarding the output for 3, it will be better for me if i could see or output in another table or somewhere else, all the possible combinations.